# How to "fill" background image?

Tags: css

I'm making a website where I need to have a notable difference between fill and center background images. My template is this:
**Center:** *Uses native resolution to determine size.*
[image]
**Fill:** *Fits sides to fill screen without changing aspect ratio. Two sides exactly fit screen, while other two are cut off.*
[image]

I managed to get centered with

```
.center {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

But I can't figure out how I would do fill. Any insight?

Comment: is it difficult to read the documentation of background-size before asking ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want `background-size: cover`. [Other background-size options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).