# Change the size of an header css

Tags: html, css

I want to change the size to my background image to 500, 100% in css, but I am unable. I already tried the background-size tag, but it didn’t work

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830964942320435211/875439626972692550/image2.png");
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Rubydium</h1>
    <h4>
      IP: rubydiumfaction.mcpe.eu
      <br>
      Port: 19595
    </h4>
  </div>
```

. This is my code:

In comments, DJ burb found an answer. It is ok, but when I add background-size: 100%;, the image is like this.

I want to the background image be responsive
[image: image1]

Comment: Will this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970640/how-to-fill-background-image

Comment: Yes. Also sorry for the duplicated post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `background-size:100% 100%`

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830964942320435211/875439626972692550/image2.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Rubydium</h1>
    <h4>
      IP: rubydiumfaction.mcpe.eu
      <br>
      Port: 19595
    </h4>
  </div>
```

you can read more about [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images) property here

Comment: It worked, but if I go on my iPad (example) il will see this https://imgur.com/a/nXguW8b but me, i want to have the original image size, but bigger (original image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830964942320435211/875439626972692550/image2.png)

Comment: you can add height to the `.header{}` please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/0b6sL4km/